# C# containskey on tuple

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

I have a dictionary that takes in a tuple function and an int

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>, int> fullNames = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>, int>();
```

Where the Tuple class is defined as

```
public class Tuple<T, T2> 
{ 
    public Tuple(T first, T2 second) 
    { 
        First = first; 
        Second = second; 
    } 
    public T First { get; set; } 
    public T2 Second { get; set; } 

}
```

I want to use the Containskey function as such

```
if (fullNames.ContainsKey(Tuple<"firstname","lastname">))
```

But I am getting an overload error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us the text of the error?

Comment: No overload for method 'ContainsKey' takes '2'

Comment: What is `Tuple<"firstname","lastname">`? Do you mean: `new Tuple("firstname", "lastname")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you have provided is invalid, since you're trying to provide a type definition in the place where an actual object should be (and the type definition is invalid too, since a string is not actually the type `System.String` that a generic expects). If the tuple is the key value for the dictionary, then you can do this:

```
if(fullNames.ContainsKey(new Tuple<string, string>("firstname", "lastname")))
```

But then you can run afoul of the reference equality issue since two tuples created in memory with the same properties are not necesarily the same object. It would be better to do this:

```
Tuple<string, string> testTuple = new Tuple<string, string>("firstname", "lastname");
if(fullNames.Keys.Any(x => x.First == testTuple.First && x.Second == testTuple.Second))
```

That will tell you if a key exists that shares the same property data. Then accessing that element is going to be just as complicated.

EDIT: Long story short, if you plan on using a reference type for your key, you need to make sure your object implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in a way to properly identify two separate in memory instances are the same.

Comment: The `<string, string>` in constructor call can be inferred from the type of constructor args, thus is redundant.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that when using the Tuple type included in .NET 4, the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are implemented as expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (fullNames.ContainsKey(new Tuple<string, string> ("firstname", "lastname")))
{ /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to use your `Tuple` as key in a Dictionary<> you need to correctly implement the methods `GetHashCode` and `Equals`:

```
public class Tuple<T, T2> 
{ 
    public Tuple(T first, T2 second) 
    { 
        First = first; 
        Second = second; 
    } 
    public T First { get; set; } 
    public T2 Second { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      return First.GetHashCode() ^ Second.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override Equals(object other)
    {
       Tuple<T, T2> t = other as Tuple<T, T2>;
       return t != null && t.First.Equals(First) && t.Second.Equals(Second);
    }

}
```

Otherwise a key equality check is done by reference. With the effect that `new Tuple("A", "B") != new Tuple("A", "B")`.

For more information about hash code generation:
[What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263400/181108)

Comment: this is the simplest solution.

Comment: +1, and the 'Equals()' method must have a return type.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.0 has a `Tuple` type, which would work for your case since the `Equal` method is overloaded to use the `Equal` from your types.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> fullNames = 
    new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>();
fullNames.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("firstname", "lastname"), 1);
Console.WriteLine(fullNames.ContainsKey(
    new Tuple<string, string>("firstname","lastname"))); //True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Tuple<type,type> tuple = new Tuple("firsdtname", "lastname")
```

You've written code to create an instance of atuple of unknown types.